# Window resize animation

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm trying to create a window that can resize when the user clicks a button.

I want to get the window to resize gradually (slowly over some time).

I got it working nice so far using this kind of logic:

```
auto CALLBACK RunUI::WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam) noexcept -> LRESULT
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    ...
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
            {
                if (wparam == VK_DOWN)
                {
                    if (!window.is_extended)
                    {
                        for (int index = APP_HEIGHT; index <= APP_HEIGHT + APP_EXTENSION; index+=10)
                        {
                            ::SetWindowPos(hwnd, nullptr, 0, 0, APP_WIDTH, index, SWP_FRAMECHANGED | SWP_NOMOVE);
                            ::Sleep(1);
                        }
                        window.is_extended = TRUE;
                        break;
                    }
                }
    ...
```

However, all the child windows (buttons, texts etc...) are disappearing during the `for` loop, but I want them to remain visible.

Is there a method to get them to not disappear or like a standard API for these kind of things? I couldn't find one and this solution seems a little hacky.

It's also worth mentioning that none of the child windows should move in relation to the top-left corner of the parent window during this - only the parent window should grow downwards a little.

Comment: Make sure you process windows message in the loop. Otherwise, you can also check this maybe AnimateWindow : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-animatewindow

Comment: Don't sleep in your wndproc! Use a timer...

Answer (score 1):

`SetWindowPos` updates the window which then receives another WM_PAINT in order to draw.

Windows messaging procedure is single-thread. That is, when you call `SetWindowPos` 10 times in the same thread before calling `GetMessage()` again, you won't have 10 updates before anything is visible.

Either use a separated thread to do that or a message-based mechanism (Use a PostMessage with a custom message that would call SetWindowPos) in a loop.